# How to generating unique token in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL and I am having an issue with unique identifier token. Here is my employee table.

Employee Table (MySQL)

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,  --  AUTO_INCREMENT    
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,     
    hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    token varchar(100) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)                   
);
```

I have employee table in MySQL. emp_no is the primary key with auto-increment. I want to have a token for each employee and the token should be unique for each employee.

The token should look something like:

```
32f41e07b9e8393ae250ad617801a155
```

How can I achieve this?

**My Approach**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 16) AS myrandomstring
```

But I don't think that the above query will guarantee uniqueness for each employee.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UUID Mysql function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) to generate an id.

From what you research, it seems that the function [UUID_SHORT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short) should be a better option.

```
mysql> SELECT UUID_SHORT();
    -> 92395783831158784
```

Comment: As emp_no is unique for each employee, can we use it to create a unique token? like appending date (DD-MM--yyyy-h-m-s) to employee id and create a unique token?

Comment: This function generates an identifier that is unique because of its great improbability to be produced several times. It can be used as a unique identifier. But to be sure and sure that this absolutely never happens, yes, we can stick today's date for example, or the Timestamp

Comment: You will not know the auto-increment primary key until you make the insertion. UUID will always be unique for each time you generated.

Comment: Thanks @Gawain for the precision

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on external libraries for that for example [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid), leave the table with regular unsigned integer ID and make another column uuid which is of typ VARCHAR(), I wouldnt count on mysql generating my UUID I'd rather do it programatically.

Comment: So create token in php and make it insert into the record? Again we end up with the same logic in PHP.

Comment: I haven't heard that ramsey/uuid ever created a duplicate id. Thats what uuid libraries are for, another benefit of programatic approach is that the uuid can come from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

UUID is a good way to generate a unique String id and will not duplicated for each time you generated.

The only concern for UUID is length, which can make index not efficient as primary key(auto-increment int). But it depends on your data size and logic need.

I would recommend to generate UUID from your client code since it much clear and easy to maintain or update if you need.